# div that is a link gets shrouded by image gallery

Tags: javascript, css

This is my website: https://alexaterfloth.com/ and I have a div/link that looks and almost works how I would like it to, the only thing is that it is placed in a fixed position and when you scroll over the image gallery the clickable images take priority, but I would like to have this link take priority. When the div is over the image gallery and you click on it, it opens the image below instead. It's the highest on z-index and appears to be in front of everything, how can I make it clickable 100% of the time and take priority over the image gallery? I would love a CSS solution but could also add a script tag with pure js.

```html
<a href="https://www.snackthoughts.net/" target="_blank">
  <div class="shop">SHOP</div>
</a>
```

here is the styling for the class:

```css
.shop{
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,2555,0.5), 0px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);  
  z-index:10;
  position:fixed;
  top:10%;
  right:5%;
  font-weight:bold;
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size:37px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
  user-select: none; /* Standard */
  border-style: outset;
  background-color:#04e482;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  border-color: #04e482;
  border-width:5px;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by this as I see now reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: So I got it working by placing the "shop" class in your <a> tag above and removing it from the <div>. But then you just need to style the SHOP text

Comment: this worked! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<a href="https://www.snackthoughts.net/" target="_new" class="shop">
  <div style="color:#FFF !important;">SHOP</div>
</a>
```